# The countable intersection of open sets is open

Tags: general-topology

I have seen the proof of countable complement topology is not metacompact ([Prove that the countable complement topology is not meta compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643749/prove-that-the-countable-complement-topology-is-not-meta-compact)). But I still do not understand this statement: " The countable intersection of open sets is open" . Why is it true?

Answer (score 5):

This is true ***in the cocountable topology*** because of the combination of these two facts:

1. $X\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}X\setminus A_n$.
2. If $A_n$ is countable for every $n\in\Bbb N$, then $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ is countable.

In general, of course, this is not true, every singleton in a metric space is the intersection of countably many open balls, but it is easy to come up with examples where there are singletons which are not open.

Answer (score 1):

This is false **in a general topological space, not necessarily in the countable complement topology**. Take, for instance, the open sets $\{(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i})\}$ in the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}\right) = \{0\}$ which is not open. This is a countable intersection (as it is indexed on $\mathbb{N}$) of open sets that is not open.

Thanks to several commenters who noted I jumped the gun on my answer.

Comment: This is not a cocountable topology.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question was not about cocountable topologies. The asker made the claim that the countable intersection of open sets is open, I provided a counterexample. Maybe it works in some special topologies, but as stated it's false.

Comment: The question is set in the context of the countable complement topology. Your example, while valid, is irrelevant to that context.

Comment: @walkar: the space in the above is an uncountable set equipped with countable complement. So your an example is not true

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see now that the asker did mention the countable complement topology, my apologies. I read too fast.

Comment: @user59363 Ah, right. I meant $(-1/i,1/i)$. I'll edit, thanks.